# Excel formula throwing error - no reason given

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have a fairly simple formula that will not calculate in Excel. This formula works just fine in Google Sheets, and nothing has changed upon moving the formula over.
`=COUNTIF(unique('_FullUsage'!$C$3:$C$2000),'_FullUsage'!$C$3:$C$2000)`

Here is the formula in Excel:
[image: photo1]

And here is the formula in Google Sheets:
[image: photo2]

This formula is part of a bigger formula that involves a filter, so I also tested it in Excel as an array formula (it works in Google Sheets as an array formula), but it would still throw the error.

I have tried googling this issue several times, and have found nothing that works.

I have checked my spelling, parentheses, and sheet names several times, and cannot find where there might be an issue. I have tested different parts of this formula separately (various ways to reference a cell/cells as well as the unique formula alone) and each work independently, but not together within the `COUNTIF` formula.

My main experience is in Google Sheets, and not Excel, so I may be missing something that I don't realize.

Comment: This is why we ask that people understand that Google-sheets and Excel are different and a formula in one may not work in the other.  In Excel COUNTIF(S) does not allow arrays as the Range criteria.  It must be a Range.  By doing UNIQUE you are returning an array.  It will not  work with COUNTIFS.

Comment: BTW, with that formula you would get an array of `1`s as counting each one in the range against a unique list will return `1`.  I think you want: `=COUNTIF('_FullUsage'!$C$3:$C$2000,unique('_FullUsage'!$C$3:$C$2000))` which will work in Excel.

Comment: @ScottCraner This is why I am posting here :) My experience is in Google Sheets and not Excel, so I would not know that difference. In Google Sheets, the criteria also specifies "range", but allows arrays, so it is not a difference that is easily noticed. Thank you for your response, and I will test that formula and see if I still get the result I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

COUNTIF requires a range input, where UNIQUE(range) produces an array, not a range. You can workaround using MMULT:

```
=LET(range, '_FullUsage'!$C$3:$C$2000,
     unq,   UNIQUE(range),
MMULT(N(TRANSPOSE(range)=unq),SEQUENCE(ROWS(range),,1,0)))
```

*Oh and like Scott Craner mentioned in the comments, you probably swapped the range and the uniques, so this would not be required anyway*

Comment: wow! Mind-blowing solution.